# Copy data from Table1 to Table2 automatically or after some time interval

Tags: database

I am using MSSQL server Enterprise edition database.
In that database I have two tables, let's say Table1, Table2.
I want to automatically copy and paste data from Table1 to Table2 on some basis. Let's say at some time interval (after every hour)  or computer startup or if any change in Table1.
The data copy from Table1 to Table2 should happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can write [`triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on table1 to propagate insert/update/delete to table2 as well. This would happen as and when table1 changes. Not sure why you would want to have two copies of same data though! are we missing something?